# Failing to filter elements strings from event list site

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am learning Python3 for web Scraping, here's my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://beijing.douban.com/events/week-all'
req = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
events = soup.find('ul',{'class':'events-list'}).findAll('li')

for event in events:
    event_details = dict()
    event_details['title']= event.find('div',{'class':'title'})
f = open('douban8.txt','a',encoding='utf-8')
print(event_details,file=f)
```

I got results looks like below:

```
**{'title': <div class="title">
<a href="https://www.douban.com/event/31568343/" itemprop="url" title="年度动作奇幻大片《海王》北京IMAX 3D零点场免费观影来了！">
<span itemprop="summary">年度动作奇幻大片《海王》北京IMAX 3D零点场免费观影来了！</span>
</a>
</div>}
{'title': None}
{'title': None}
{'title': None}
{'title': None}**
```

All I want is the string between tags, but I cannot get rid of the tags from the whole text. I tried .string or .text and some other methods ,all failed. Could anyone give me some advice please?

#

many thank to @sohan-das, I update the code here:

```
import requests
url = 'https://beijing.douban.com/events/week-all'
req = requests.get(url)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,'html.parser')
events = soup.find('ul',{'class':'events-list'}).findAll('li')

for event in events:

    event_details=dict()
    try:
        event_details['title'] = event.find('div'{'class','title'}).text.strip()
        f = open('douban9.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
        print(event_details, file=f)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    continue
```

It works now

Comment: did you use `.strip()` or `.text.encode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: yes,I tried. But always with error msg: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', I really don't know why

Comment: use try except to avoid AttributeError:, i think it should work!

Comment: Oh,thank you very much, I use try except pair to pass AttributeError, and then everything works! please add a answer to this please, then I can click a vote on it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`event_details` need to be list not dict and place it outside loop. element in `events` list has more than 10 elements you need to filter it.

```
.....
events = soup.find('ul', {'class':'events-list'}).findAll('li')

event_details = []
for event in events:
    event_title = event.find('div', {'class':'title'})
    # if element not have div.title skip
    if event_title:
        event_details.append({'title' : event_title.text.strip()}) 

f = open('douban8.txt','a',encoding='utf-8')
print(event_details,file=f)
```

Results

```
[
  {'title': '年度动作奇幻大片《海王》北京IMAX 3D零点场免费观影来了！'},
  ....,
  {'title': '在被认可前，先让自己更专业！「42时」纪录片导演制作班第二季'}
]
```